# Update values dynamically in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm working on an inventory management app, and I need to update inventories according to a value provided by the user. Let's say we have 5 of one item, the user adds 3 on the front-end form, the updated value should be 8.
I've been unable to make mongo update the number.

```
router.put('/show/:id', isLoggedIn, catchAsync(async(req, res)=>{
const {id} = req.params;
const qty = parseInt(req.body.cantidad)
if(qty>0){
    const item = await Inv.findById(id)
    const update = parseInt(req.body.cantidad) + item.cantidad
    const updateInv = await Inv.findOneAndUpdate({ item: {cantidad:{$in: update}}}, {new :true})
    res.redirect(`/inv/show/${item._id}`)
} else {
    req.flash('error', 'Revise la cantidad')
    res.redirect('/inv/show')
}}));
```

And here's my model:

```
const InvSchema = new Schema({
nombre: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
},
cantidad: Number
});
```

Comment: I can't understand your code completely but I think maybe you don't know that `findByIdAndUpdate` returns the old value. You should pass `{new :true}` as the third argument to get the new value.

Comment: @PouriaMoosavi I looked it up on the mongoose docs, here's the updated code `const update = parseInt(req.body.cantidad) + item.cantidad
        const updateInv = await Inv.findByIdAndUpdate(id, update, {new :true})`
still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't change your update statement right. You shouldn't remove the first argument. As I said `{new: true}` should be the third input.
Anyway I think there is a better solution for what you want to do. As you already find the record with `findById`, you can use mongo/monoose `save` command instead of another `findOneAndUpdate`:

```js
router.put('/show/:id', isLoggedIn, catchAsync(async(req, res)=>{
  const {id} = req.params;
  const qty = parseInt(req.body.cantidad)
  if(qty>0){
    const item = await Inv.findById(id)
    item.cantidad = parseInt(req.body.cantidad) + item.cantidad // Change this line to change item's property directly
    await item.save() // Save the item in database
    //const updateInv = await Inv.findOneAndUpdate({ item: {cantidad:{$in: update}}}, {new :true}) // Remove this line
    res.redirect(`/inv/show/${item._id}`)
  } else {
    req.flash('error', 'Revise la cantidad')
    res.redirect('/inv/show')
  }
}));
```

I think this is a cleaner approach.

Comment: it works! thank you so much. Truth is, the place where I learned mongo + node didn't cover this type of situations so I was really scratching my head here. Thank you so much again.